# Using splice with nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have an array in which all the elements are also arrays (of integers), called `mainArray`.
I am trying to use `splice()` to add and remove its elements (subarrays).

Initially `mainArray` has a single element (an Array with one integer), I wish to delete it and add 3 new subarrays to `mainArray`, these are defined in arraysToAdd.

```
mainArray = new Array(new Array(1));
arraysToAdd = new Array(new Array(1,2), new Array(1,4), new Array(1,7));

alert(arraysToAdd.length); // Returns: 3: as expected

mainArray.splice(0,1,arraysToAdd);

alert(mainArray.length); // Returns: 1: I want this to be 3
```

I expect the length of `mainArray` at the end to be 3 (as it should contain 3 subarrays), but it seems `splice()` is flattening `arraysToAdd` and so `mainArray` ends up just being an array of integers.

What am I missing?

Comment: `console.log(mainArray)`

Comment: *"but it seems `splice()` is flattening `arraysToAdd`"* Uhm, how can the length of `mainArray` be `1` if the other arrays is flattened into `mainArray`? If `mainArray` was an array of integers, wouldn't the length be 6?

Comment: You do know you can just type `var mainArray = [[1]];`, right?

Comment: @PHPglue brings up a good point. In fact, your `mainArray` worked because you didn't use the value, but if you had tried to use it, or if you created it with a greater number, you'd get a result that you may not expect. Like if you did `new Array(3)`, you now have an Array with `.length === 3`, and no actual defined members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're missing is that you're adding an Array of Arrays to your Array of Arrays. You want to add each individual Array instead.

You can use `.apply()` to do this:

```
mainArray.splice.apply(mainArray, [0,1].concat(arraysToAdd));
```

So the `0` and `1` arguments you passed are joined with your `arraysToAdd` to form the arguments that you're going to pass to `.splice()` via `.apply()`.

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/QLwLA/

---

Without `.apply()`, you would have needed to add them individually, like this:

```
mainArray.splice(0, 1, arraysToAdd[0], arraysToAdd[1], arraysToAdd[2]);
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/QLwLA/1/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
mainArray.splice(0, 1, ...arraysToAdd)
```